# change radio value with form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the value of a radio button with a form input: https://jsfiddle.net/91oz4nfL/

Essentially by default I want it to be NO but if the argument is triggered then change the radio button to YES

```
function calculateBMI() {

  var weight = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('input2').value / 100;
  var output = document.getElementById('output');

  var bmi = ((weight) / (height * height));

  var result = ""
  if (bmi > 22) {
    result = "Change question radio to yes!";
  }

  bmi = bmi.toFixed(2);

  if (bmi && bmi != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
    output.innerHTML = result;
    output.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    output.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.getElementById('input1').addEventListener('keyup', calculateBMI);
document.getElementById('input2').addEventListener('keyup', calculateBMI);
```

Comment: `Radio9.checked = true;`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan would that live in the if statement?

Comment: Yep: https://jsfiddle.net/91oz4nfL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add a few lines in your if statement, like so

```
if (bmi > 22) {
    document.getElementById("Radio9").checked = true;
    result = "Change question radio to yes!";
} else {
    document.getElementById("Radio10").checked = true;
}
```

If a radio button is `true` this means that it is checked. The above code sets the 'Yes' radio button to checked if `bmi` is greater than 22, otherwise sets the 'No' radio button to true.

https://jsfiddle.net/91oz4nfL/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var radioYes = document.getElementById('Radio9');
  var radioNo = document.getElementById('Radio10');
  var weight = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('input2').value / 100;
  var output = document.getElementById('output');

  var bmi = ((weight) / (height * height));

  var result = ""
  debugger
  if (bmi > 22) {
    result = "Change question radio to yes!";
    radioYes.checked = true;
  }else{
    radioNo.checked = false;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n820pz3e/1/